# Would a 0.3 micron filter be effective in blocking formaldehyde fumes produced by curing cyanoacrylate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, equipment

I’m looking into purchasing a mask that blocks particles larger than or equal to 0.3 μm in size. I’m hoping it blocks the formaldehyde fumes produced by curing cyanoacrylate.

How effective such mask would be, i.e. would the size of formaldehyde fume particles be greater than or equal to 0.3 microns?

Comment: Don't know.  Formaldehyde could be present as a gas rather than an aerosol, in which case the particles would be molecule-size.   I'd thus get a mask that fits either of these cartridges:   https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/p/d/v000057398/  or https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/p/d/v000152051/.  Depending on the conentration, you might want to seal your eyes off (using goggles) as well.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the half-masks these cartridges are used in are a tight seal compared to, say, the classic paper and cloth masks we’ve seen through the pandemic? I only ask bec it is crucial that my breath is not able to leak out the top of the mask near my eyes. Is it a tight/snug fit round the nose bridge?

Comment: These masks are made of a rubbery material that should seal to your face better than cloth or plastic, assuming (a)if you're  a guy, you're clean-shaven; and (b) the mask fits well. Fit is critical. If you were in industry or academia, you'd undergo a fit test to check this (https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/respiratory-protection-us/support/center-for-respiratory-protection/fit-testing/). On your own, you'll need to use your best judgement (which in your case at least means you can't smell any formaldehyde). You'll just need to order some on AZ and try them. The 3M 5203 Medium fits many faces well.

Comment: Generally, put in questions enough relevant details and background to avoid needed clarification or possible misunderstanding.

Comment: @theorist so sorry to bother you again, but would either of these filters be suitable in blocking out formaldehyde fumes? I’m in Aus so I’m having to use the Aus site for faster delivery. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @theorist https://www.3m.com.au/3M/en_AU/p/d/v100561013/, https://www.3m.com.au/3M/en_AU/p/d/v000057497/?preselect=8745506+8784387

Comment: @theorist does the fact the first link says “A1 form” mean anything?

Comment: You can see from their respective descriptions that 3M says they're effective against formaldehyde. The question is what percent of the fumes they block out and/or up to what level of formaldehyde are they safe to use with. For this more detailed info., an answer to what "A1 form" means, and also to get a link to a table showing what masks these cartridges work with, I would recommend contacting 3M directly for guidance. You can find their contact info. on their website.

Comment: And of course you should also look into having good ventilation. That, plus the mask, will be better than the mask by itself.  And for eye protection from fumes, if you're not going to wear a full face mask, swim goggles will work if you don't need to wear them for an extended period of time (too long and they get uncomfortable and/or fog up).  Just get some "no-tears" gentle shampoo (baby shampoo works), put a tiny drop onto the inside surface of the goggles, and gently buff dry; you can do this with your thumbs (no water needed). That will work as an effective anti-fog agent.